# app update to play store, app store and huawei store with react native cli

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I rewrote an application that was previously made and published with react native expo, with react native cli. I want to send this application to app store, play store and huawei store as an update.

For the application made with expo;
android version: 8.0.2
ios version:10

In the project with the cli it appears as version: 1.0.

In which version should I throw the application I just wrote?

Comment: Are you asking if app store deployment is possible using the React Native CLI?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.